# Tensorflow-lite deployed on Arduino example sketch hello_world

Tags: arduino, tensorflow-lite

when I try to verify the code, the IDE tells me that it fails to compile the  board program. I have only tried on Windows

```
extern int tflite_micro_main(int argc, char* argv[]);

void setup() {
  tflite_micro_main(0, NULL);
}

void loop() {
}
```

In file included from C:\Users\jangi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\hello_world\src\tensorflow\lite\core\api\error_reporter.cpp:15:0:

C:\Users\jangi\Documents\Arduino\libraries\hello_world\src/tensorflow/lite/core/api/error_reporter.h:18:19: fatal error: cstdarg: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be building against Arduino Uno which is not supported for now. The official example works with Arduino Nano 33 BLE - you can find it in the board manager.